# PHP complicated if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a PHP if statement like so:

```
<?php if(!in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], array("/page.php", "/", "/index.php", "/design-centre.php"))) { ?>

     //Do Something

<?php } ?>
```

What I am trying do is say if not page.php, /, index.php or design-centre.php and if `!isset($_GET['action'])` for page.php ONLY then do something.

Comment: Ok and its not working? Or whats the problem?

Comment: I have no idea how it would look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think would be better if you first create an array of the involved pages/url/nodes/etc...

```
$pages = array(
    "root" => "/",
    "page" => "/page.php",
    "index" => "/index.php",
    "design-centre" => "/design-centre.php"
);
```

Then you can check if the current `scriptname` isn't in `pages` array and in case it's equal to `pages.php` but the querystring doesn't have the key `action`

```
if( !in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $pages) AND ( !isset($_GET['action']) AND $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == $pages['page']))
{ 
    //Do something
}
```

In my opinion it would be better to take off your criteria from the if condition and to give them a more readable function wrapper, for example something like this (in a procedural way):

```
$pages = array(
    "root" => "/",
    "page" => "/page.php",
    "index" => "/index.php",
    "design-centre" => "/design-centre.php"
);

function weAreOnMyCriteriaPages($pages)
{
    return in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $pages);
}

function weAreOnThisPage($match)
{
    return $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == $match;
}
```

In this way your conditional check will be:

```
if( !weAreOnMyCriteriaPages($pages) AND ( !isset($_GET['action']) AND weAreOnThisPage($pages['page'])))
{ 
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_GET['action']) && !in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], array("/page.php", "/", "/index.php", "/design-centre.php"))) { ?>

     //Do Something

<?php } ?>
```

This code adds `!isset($_GET['action']) &&` inside the if statement.
The `&&`operator means that you are making a logical AND operation so then both statements the `in_array()` one and the `!isset($_GET['action'])`one are required to jump inside the `if`

Comment: Some lines of explanation instead of just `Try this:` could make a more valuable answer out of it.

Comment: Indeed, I will add some

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to define the array outside of the if statement, it would make it easier to look at and also allow for easier revisions down the road.

Comment: this does not work :( I was looking for if not in array and if $_GET['action'] is not set for page.php only